# Can "more importantly" go in the middle of a sentence?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

I've only seen *more importantly* appear at the beginning of a sentence. Or being preceded by a conjunction (e.g. *and, more importantly*).

Can it appear in the middle of a sentence without a conjunction?

Example:

> He wanted to know what her words meant, more importantly, what they
> implied.

Comment: If the first comma was a semi colon, it'd be fine ... or you need "and" there: *He wanted to know what her words meant and, more importantly, what they implied.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason the conjunction is needed is *where* in the sentence it's been inserted.

> He wanted to know, more importantly, what they implied.

Now, in fairness, that sentence *probably* would have started with "and." Because this is a "more" phrase, which means something is being compared. I've cheated by surely breaking your example sentence into two. I might get away without an "and"...

> He wanted to hear her words again. He wanted, more importantly, to know what they meant.

... but an "and" is at least implied in the context. But yeah, you can create sentences that don't grammatically need it to be present outright.